# How to filter and/or sort user taxonomy query inside custom user taxonomy archive page?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-user-query

I am looking for some assistance with how I can filter AND/OR sort my WP query while on a taxonomy page. Essentially, what I am looking to do is have all users listed in alphabetical order on the front end, rather than date joined. I have a custom user taxonomy called `bus_category` and am editing inside `taxonomy-bus_category.php` currently. I would also like to eventually filter this list, but assume SORTING and FILTERING would take place at the same level.

Here's what I have:

```
<?php
$term_id = get_queried_object_id();
$term = get_queried_object(); 

$users = get_objects_in_term( $term_id, $term->taxonomy );
?>
            <?php
if ( !empty( $users ) ) {
?>
    <?php foreach ( $users as $user_id ) { ?>
<?php 
$user_name = get_the_author_meta ( 'nickname', $user_id );
$user_url = get_the_author_meta( 'user_url', $user_id );
$state = get_the_author_meta( 'state', $user_id );
$description = get_the_author_meta( 'description', $user_id );
$artist_image = get_field('artist_image', 'user_'. $user_id );

// Get the user object.
$user = get_userdata( $user_id );

// Get all the user roles as an array.
$user_roles = $user->roles;
?>
<?php if ( in_array( 'role_4', $user_roles, true ) ) : ?>
            <div class="jobs">
                    <div class="avatar">
                    <?php if ( get_field('artist_image', 'user_'. $user_id ) ): ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $artist_image ?>" alt="<?php echo $user_name ?>'s Artist Image" title="<?php echo $user_name ?>'s Artist Image">
                    <?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
                </div>          
            <h2 class="jobstitle"><?php echo $user_name ?></h2>
            <div class="description">
                <div class="locatedin">Located in: <?php echo $state ?></div>
                <?php echo $description ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $user_url; ?>" class="button" rel="nofollow" title="<?php echo $user_name ?>'s Website">Visit Website</a>
            </div>
            </div>
<?php else: ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I think I am needing to modify `get_queried_objects`, but I am not 100% certain if it functions the same way with user taxonomies, if I can do it on the `taxonomy-bus_category.php` page itself, or I need to filter all of the WP query conditionally in `functions.php`. Apologies if my code is messy/wrong, I'm still new at this.

Comment: have you looked into the `pre_get_posts` filter?

Comment: hmmm I see now you're using Users not posts. I was confused as you tagged this with `wp-query` which queries posts, not users. I would be ***extremely*** suspicious of `the_author_meta` since there is no author, posts have authors. Use `get_user_meta` to get a users meta, don't abuse `the_author_meta`. Can you confirm that this is a user taxonomy and you're attempting to use that taxonomies frontend templates to display those users? I don't understand what you're trying to filter by as the only thing you can filter by s the thing you're already filtering by

Comment: Are you asking how to list the taxonomy terms as links so you can click through and browse just the users on those terms? If so I'm not sure how this is different from doing the same thing with post categories, just use the terms link. Or are you trying to implement faceted intersections? Can you update your question to be more specific/clearer? I think you've assumed some parts and missed them out from your question because they seem obvious. Also you mention WP Query in your last paragraph, WP Query is a post query, _not_ a user query

Comment: Right now, my code prints all users in a certain role (`role_4`), and in a certain category on the page. The category is passed through `get_queried_object`. My goal is to give an additional parameter to organize the users alphabetically instead of by date joined.

Yes, this is a user taxonomy, but `the_author_meta` does appear to work fine when I use it.

Comment: So you do not want to filter, you actually want to sort/order? You should stop using `the_author_meta`, it's being misused, switch to `get_user_meta` instead

Comment: Okay. So does switching that allow me to sort? Or are you just informing me of other issues in my code?